# Issue on testing ipa

Tags: ios, http, xcode7, ipa, tls1.2

We have an iOS App that is fully functional , the description is as following..
 This App is fetching data from a website and we are showing the data at our mobile devices
everything goes well during testing. but when we build an ipa file, the web API do not gets call.

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>
```

Comment: Any logs from XCode?

Comment: First, please share some log, second please check your Schemas. Check your #if DEBUG conditions.